# What does SQLAlchemy all() return when there are no resuls

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I think I may be able to simplify this if [`.all()` in SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html?highlight=all#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.all) returns an empty list if no results are found. Please advise:

```
@classmethod
def list_for(cls, account_id):
    result = list()
    rows = Session.query(UserAbility).filter_by(account_id=account_id)
    for row in rows:
        result.append(row.ability_id)
    return result
```

Comment: It does return an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation says, `all()` returns the result of the query as a list. Therefore an empty result is returned as ...

Furthermore since you seem to use the IDs only, you can query `UserAbility.ability_id`, and do

```
return [i[0] for i in Session.query(UserAbility.ability_id).filter_by(account_id=account_id).all()]
```